# Como configurar o angular-cli-ghpages para fazer deploy em outro repositório diferente?

Tags: angular, deploy, github

Tô com um projeto Angular no GitHub e fiz o deploy pro GitHub Pages. Instalei o angular-cli-ghpages e rodei o comando `ng deploy --base-href=` com o link pro ghpages do repositório. Funciona, ele cria a branch "gh-pages" onde tem apenas a pasta de build e no link do gh-pages também fica certinho o projeto. Mas o que acontece:

Eu queria que esse repositório tivesse o código do projeto e outro repositório tivesse apenas o deploy, a pasta de build e ele fosse o repositório em que estivesse configurado o ghpages.

O que eu fiz: nesse repositório do código do projeto eu rodei o comando de deploy, mas configurei o base href pro link de outro repositório onde está configurado o ghpages. Ele gerou a branch ghpages. Ai eu peguei esse pasta de build e movi pro repositório de deploy, e apaguei a branch ghpages desse repo do projeto. Como o base-href tava configurado pra esse repo de deploy, ele ficou no ar.

Eu tenho, então, o repositório com o código todo do projeto e outro repositório com o código de build e o ghpages configurado com o projeto no ar, exatamente como eu queria.

Mas, se eu for fazer outro deploy, vou ter que fazer esse trabalho todo de novo: buildar, mover os arquivos pro outro repo e apagar. Há alguma forma de configurar isso automaticamente? Ou usando outra funcionalidade como esse angular-cli-ghpages? Porque teoricamente ele teria que buildar e pushar esse código de build pra outro repo.

[Repositório do projeto](https://github.com/christyanbrayan/pokedex)

[Repositório de deploy](https://github.com/christyanbrayan/pokedex-deploy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagino que você esteja usando um ambiente Linux. Para configurar o angular-cli-ghpages para fazer o deploy em um repositório diferente, você precisará seguir esses passos:

1. Instale o pacote angular-cli-ghpages executando o seguinte comando no seu terminal:

> npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages

2. Faça login no seu GitHub e crie um novo repositório para armazenar seus arquivos de build.
3. Navegue até o diretório raiz do seu projeto Angular e execute o seguinte comando para criar uma build de produção:

> ng build --prod --base-href "https://[username].github.io/[repo-name]/"

4. Execute o seguinte comando para fazer o deploy na branch gh-pages do seu novo repositório:

> ngh --dir=dist/[project-name]

5. Substitua [username] e [repo-name] pelo seu usuário e nome do repositório, respectivamente. E [project-name] pelo nome do seu projeto.
6. Se você quiser mudar a branch para deploy, pode usar esse comando:

> ngh --dir=dist/[project-name] --branch=branch-name

1. Agora você pode acessar seu projeto hospedado em `https://[username].github.io/[repo-name]/`
2. Isso deve configurar o angular-cli-ghpages para fazer o deploy em um repositório diferente. Lembre-se de que essas configurações precisam ser feitas cada vez que você quiser fazer um novo deploy.

Lembre-se também que, se você usa uma conta de organização para seu repositório, você precisa incluir o nome da organização no lugar do seu nome de usuário. A url deve ficar assim: `https://[organization-name].github.io/[repo-name]`

Além disso, é importante verificar se sua conta tem permissão para publicar em repositórios de organização, caso contrário, o comando não irá funcionar.